# How does child window inherit css style from parent window in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I write a function to create a new Window(child window).

```
        openReportsWindow:function(content){
        window.name = "parentWin";
        var h = screen.height;
        var w = screen.width;
        if(window.childWrep == null){
            var childWrep = window.open("", 'repWin','left=0,top=0,resizable=yes,status=yes,width='+w +',height=' +h+'');
            childWrep.document.write(content);
            childWrep.document.close();
            childWrep.name = 'repWin';
            window.childWrep = childWrep;
        } else {
            window.blur();
            if(window.childWrep.closed == false){
                childWrep.document.write(content);
                childWrep.document.close();
                setTimeout(function(){window.childWrep.focus()},1000);
            } else{
                var childWrep = window.open("", 'repWin','left=0,top=0,resizable=yes,status=yes,width='+w +',height=' +h+'');
                childWrep.document.write(content);
                childWrep.document.close();
                childWrep.name = 'repWin';
                window.childWrep = childWrep;
            }
        }
    }
```

and put html into this child window in this way.

```
        render : function() {

        var context = {
                data: data
                ...
        };

        this.openReportsWindow(this.template(context));

    }
```

Here is the problem.
How do you inherit css style from parent window?
And how do you trigger an event in the child window?

Comment: Either write the css inside a `<style>` tag in the head of the window, just like you do with the other HTML ( inlcude it in the template ). Or insert a link to the stylesheet you want to use. If the child window is mostly static content, I would actually create a seperate HTML page for it and open that with `window.open()` instead of fully populating it from inside the parent window.

Comment: I am guessing that the questions are worded wrong and it is is meant to say "How do you inherit css style from parent window" and "How do you trigger an event in the child window"

Comment: @epascarello thanks for correcting me. That's what I want to ask.

Answer (score 0):

To copy parents styles you can use .style property, just use a element selector for the parent and child element, and assign child.style property equals to parents.style.

Example:

```
let $parent = document.getElementById('parenID')
let $child = document.getElementById('childID')
$child.style = parent.style
```

Comment: how do you implement it between parent window and child window?